# php soap client gets Server java.lang.NullPointerException when authentication is ok

Tags: java, php, web-services, authentication, soap-client

If You are sending an object to a webmethod to use it as prameter:
 Example: sending an object that will be represented as a class in the server like this:

```
   $creditCard = new stdClass();
   $creditCard->number="705";
   $creditCard->expiryDate="03/10/2019";
   $creditCard->controlNumber=9;
   $param = array("creditCard" => $creditCard);

   $Response = $client->__soapCall('valider', array($param));
```

You won't get any property of the class CreditCard that is in the server to work, and every time you do creditClass.getNumber() or trying to use accessors you will get a null pointer error because your object is not really created.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem you have to modify the server webservice and not the client: you have to add the trivial jax-ws annotation @webParam:

```
  public String valider(@WebParam(name = "creditCard")CreditCard creditCard){ ... }
```

And your PHP soapClient code is very simple: (if you want more security you have to encode your credentials or use an other way for authentication like digest authentication or other jax ws security implementations)

```
   try { 
      $opts = array (
        'http' => [
        'header' => "username: myrealname\r\n".
                   'password: pass1myrealpassword'] 
        );
      $par= array(
            'trace' => 1,
              'exceptions' =>0,
             'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_1,
             'connection_timeout' => 1800,
             'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts),
               );

      $client = new SoapClient($wsdl,$par);
     //...... and call your service method as you do
```